# Function doesn't appear in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reproduce this game from the w3 website. My canvas shows but ever since I added movement functions my object (`var myGamePiece`) AKA red square, stopped showing. Feel free to inspect. I checked 10 times for any typos or anything but couldn't find any, code shows no errors. Seriously don't know what the hell is going on. I spent hours trying to make it work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script>
    
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 600;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}

var myGamePiece;
function startGame () {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}


function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
      ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
}

</script>

<button onclick="moveup()">UP</button>
<button onclick="movedown()">DOWN</button>
<button onclick="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
<button onclick="moveright()">RIGHT</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are never calling `updateGameArea`

Comment: And you have two `startGame` functions that do different things.

Comment: to Seblor, i am not sure i understand. i added this line of code ' updateGameArea.startGame(); ' under the 'function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update(); ' part but it doesnt work, is there something i am missing?

Comment: to Federico Culloca, i tried deleting the second startGame function but it doesnt work. still doesnt show anything.

Answer (score 2):

You have written multiple startGame function. please remove the top one. 
Also the main problem is that you forgot to update game area after an interval and a clear function in myGameArea object. so the code should be like below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script>

var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 600;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

var myGamePiece;
function startGame () {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}


function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
      ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
}

</script>

<button onclick="moveup()">UP</button>
<button onclick="movedown()">DOWN</button>
<button onclick="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
<button onclick="moveright()">RIGHT</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/MWWvKWq?editors=1000

Comment: i tried your method and it worked! but i am bit WTFed, because in the original section i didnt call any interval, so i couldnt forget to call clear function. what does set interval and clear function do in this case? If you wouldnt mind to specify, thank you for your solution.

Comment: The setInterval creates a continuous call of the function updateGameArea for every 20 ms. If you look at the updateGameArea function, you will see that it calls the clear method which clears the canvas (which also clears out the red rectangle), gets the new position of the game piece (by adding/substracting the speeds) and creates a new game piece in the updated position. It happens so fast that it looks like the piece is moving. But what happens is that it clears and create a new piece every 20ms. and also, when you call the start function of gameArea, the interval starts :)

Comment: Smart! thanks for explanation, your method works, i ended up going for a simple function mentioned by Aimal Khan, but i understand a bit more how this works, you the best bro.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `updateGameArea`  at start and after `moveup`, `moveDown`, `moveLeft` and `moveRight`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    


var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 600;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
startGame();

var myGamePiece;
function startGame () {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    updateGameArea();
}


function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
      ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }  
    this.clear = function() {
      ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    }
    
    
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGamePiece.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
    updateGameArea();
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
    updateGameArea();
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
    updateGameArea();
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
    updateGameArea();
}

</script>

<button onclick="moveup()">UP</button>
<button onclick="movedown()">DOWN</button>
<button onclick="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
<button onclick="moveright()">RIGHT</button>

</body>
</html>
```